# How to delete all records matching a certain value in a FireDAC dataset?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a usual `while not EOF do` loop that deletes certain records from a memory table. Deleting the last record does not signal EOF as expected. Here's my code:

```
mtCt.First;  
while Not mtCt.Eof do  
begin  
  if mtCtAmt.Value = 0.0 then
    mtCt.Delete
  else
    mtCt.Next;  
end;
```

How can I delete all records matching a certain value in a FireDAC dataset?

Comment: That's right. Delete does not change the current row... you must Delete and then Next to see if there are any more rows. Deleting a table row is not like deleting an object from an object list.

Comment: @Frazz I understand this is years later but it seems in _Delphi 10.4 / Sidney_ (possibly before), `Delete()` _does_ advance to the next record. [Link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Delete) : _Deletes the active record and positions the dataset on the next record._ A test confirmed this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior with all Delphi datasets.

If your deleting logic is as simple as your example, you can simply ignore this, anyway the next iteration will not satisfy the deleting condition, issuing a Next and going EOF.

If instead the logic is complex and you need to avoid the unnecessary iteration, you may use a trick like this:

```
var
  PrevRecNo: Integer;
begin
  mtCt.First;  
  while Not mtCt.Eof do  
  begin  
    if mtCtAmt.Value = 0.0 then
    begin
      // save the current record number 
      PrevRecNo := mtCt.RecNo;

      // delete will normally not change current record number
      // unless you've deleted the last record, in this case
      // the current record will be one less than before
      mtCt.Delete;

      // so, if the saved record number and the current one are
      // different, you've delete the last record, just issue a
      // Next in order to hit EOF and exit the while loop
      if mtCt.RecNo <> PrevRecNo then
        mtCt.Next;
    end
    else
      mtCt.Next;  
  end;
```

Comment: Sorry but why a downvote? I use regularly this technique in a lot of places and it behaves exactly as the OP asked for. It's also very simple and straightforward.

Comment: Code looks reasonable and is well commented. Wish down-voters would at least leave a comment. Will up-vote to restore rep.

Comment: @Bozzy Your suggestion works fantastic. Sorry but I was still a rookie in using this fantastic site and did not realize that I had to accept the answer. I just know I send no downvote

Comment: @Gerhard I know it wasn't you to give that downvote, it was someone else some days ago, apparently without any reason. Thank you for accepting my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must goto last data.

```
mtCt.Last;  
while Not mtCt.Bof do  
begin  
  if mtCtAmt.Value = 0.0 then
    mtCt.Delete
  else
    mtCt.Prior;  
end;
```

Comment: This code will evaluate every non-matching row preceded by a matching row two times. Also BOF will not be True when you delete the first row, exactly as EOF will not when you delete the last row (giving there are still rows in the dataset, otherwise BOF and EOF will be both True).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the internal storage without navigating dataset this way, for example:

```pascal
function GetFieldIndex(Dataset: TFDDataSet; const FieldName: string): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := 0 to Dataset.Table.Columns.Count-1 do
    if Dataset.Table.Columns[I].Name = FieldName then
    begin
      Result := I;
      Break;
    end;
end;

procedure DeleteFromDataset(Dataset: TFDDataSet; const FieldName: string;
  const FieldValue: Variant);
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
begin
  Col := GetFieldIndex(Dataset, FieldName);
  if Col <> -1 then
  begin
    Dataset.BeginBatch;
    try
      { delete all rows without navigating through dataset; this should
        affect also rows that were about to be inserted but changes were
        not yet applied }
      for Row := Dataset.Table.Rows.Count-1 downto 0 do
        if Dataset.Table.Rows[Row].GetData(Col) = FieldValue then
          Dataset.Table.Rows[Row].Delete;
      { resync dataset with the just modified internal storage }
      Dataset.Resync([]);
    finally
      Dataset.EndBatch;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
DeleteFromDataset(FDMemTable, 'MyField', 0.0);
```